# Powershell not sending the right path for a file as argument

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to apply a hash function to all the files inside a folder as some kind of version control. The idea is to make a testfile that lists the name of the file and the generated checksum. Digging online I found some code that should do the trick (in theory):

```
$list = Get-ChildItem 'C:\users\public\documents\folder' -Filter *.cab
$sha1 = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1CryptoServiceProvider 

foreach ($file in $list) {
$return = "" | Select Name, Hash

$returnname = $file.Name
$returnhash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.Name)))
$return = "$returnname,$returnhash"

Out-File -FilePath .\mylist.txt -Encoding Default -InputObject ($return) -Append
}
```

When I run it however, I get an error because it tries to read the files from c:\users\me\, the folder where I'm running the script. And the file c:\users\me\aa.cab does not exist and hence can't be reached.

I've tried everything that I could think of, but no luck. I'm using Windows 7 with Powershell 2.0, if that helps in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with .FullName instead of just .Name.

`$returnhash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($sha1.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file.FullName)))`